# Get R scripts from on-line scripts collection

Tags: qgis, r, qgis-processing

I have QGIS 2.18 installed on Win 10, I tried to add online R scripts from processing toolbox, but i get errors.

"Python error: An error has occurred while executing Python code: See message log (Python Error) for more details."

I have already activated R and configured the path folders from the providers window

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Download](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/) R-3.5.1 for windows from here, then change R folder path in provider window like that

[image]